# How to fix Bootstrap Table excessive width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is what the table looks like:

[image]

Why is the `Link` column taking so much space? This is my code:

Please let me know how can I fix this, so it takes only the required space and not so much excessive space?

```html
<table border="1" class="table table-bordered table-hover ">
  <thead class="table-dark">
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">id</th>
      <th class="text-center">Name</th>
      <th class="text-center">Image</th>
      <th class="text-center">Link</th>
      <th class="text-center">Edit</th>
      <th class="text-center">Delete</th>
      <!-- <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Delete</th> -->
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody class="">
    <?php
                                include('dbcon.php');
                                $getKey =   $_GET['token'];
                                $ref = "Home/$getKey/items";
                                $getdata = $database->getReference($ref)->getValue();
                                // print_r( $getdata);
                                $i = 0;
                                if ($getdata > 0) {
                                    foreach ($getdata as $key => $row) {
    
                                        $i++;
                                ?>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-center">
          <?php echo $i; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
          <?php echo $row['name']; ?>
        </td>

        <td class="text-center">
          <?php
                                                echo '<img src="' . $row['images'] . '" width="80" height="80" />';
                                                ?>
        </td>

        <td class=" text-center">
          <?php
                                                echo  $row['click'];
                                                ?>
        </td>

        <!-- <td class="text-center">
                                                <a href="getDetails.php?token=<?php echo $key; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
                                            </td> -->

        <td class="text-center">
          <a href="edit.php?token=<?php echo $key; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
          <form action="deletecode.php" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="ref_token_delete" value="<?php echo $key; ?>">
            <button type="submit" name="delete_data" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <?php
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    ?>
        <?php
                                }
                                ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you can use `<th width="10%">` and thereby assign a relative width to each column

Comment: Not Working , its still the same

Comment: The custom width seems to work on a jsfiddle, could you make a fiddle reproducing the issue so we can debug?

Comment: You might bet better help if you posted rendered HTML instead of your backend code. Bootstrap is a frontend library. Please update the snippet I added to your post with HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Please use CSS classes of columns, by default in Bootstrap 12 columns available, so you can distribute classes `col-1`, `col-2`, etc. across your table to make an appropriate layout. Please check the example https://codepen.io/alekskorovin/pen/mdBbVYr

```html
<table border="1" class="table table-bordered table-hover ">
  <thead class="table-dark">
      <tr>
          <th class="text-center">id</th>
          <th class="text-center">Name</th>
          <th class="text-center">Image</th>
          <th class="text-center">Link</th>
          <th class="text-center">Edit</th>
          <th class="text-center">Delete</th>
          <!-- <th>Email</th>
          <th>Delete</th> -->
      </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody class="">

              <tr>
                  <td class="text-center col-2">id</td>
                  <td class="text-center col-2">name</td>

                  <td class="text-center col-2">
                      <img src="' . $row['images'] . '" width="80" height="80" />
                  </td>

                  <td class=" text-center col-2">
                      http://stackoverflow.com</td>



                  <td class="text-center col-2">
                      <a href="edit.php?token=<?php echo $key; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
                  </td>
                  <td class="text-center col-2">
                      <form action="deletecode.php" method="POST">
                          <input type="hidden" name="ref_token_delete" value="<?php echo $key; ?>">
                          <button type="submit" name="delete_data" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                      </form>
                  </td>
              </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```